# I want to put some Names out with __repr__

Tags: python

```
class student:
     # dict = {
     # 'firstname': 'Hello',
     # 'surname': 'Name',
     # 'number': '123456',
     # 'date of birth': '01 .01.01 '}

     def __str__(self, firstname, surname, number, birthdate):
         self.firstname = firstname
         self.surname = surname
         self.number = number
         self.birthdate = birthdate

     # Person1 = student("Hello", "Name", 123456, "01/01/2000")

     Def grade_input (self, coursename, coursenote):
         self.cname = coursename (input ("course name:"))
         self.cgrade = coursgrade (float (input ("cours grade:")))
         print (coursename)
         print (coursegrade)

     def grade_cleanings (self):
         print (student.grade_input())

     def grades_trick (self):
         print ("")


# Person1= student("Hello", "Nem", 123456, "01/01/2000")
print (student.__str__("Hello", "Name", 123456, "01.01.2000"))
```

Maybe you can help me what i can do if i want to make table with subjects and grades.. 
The error status:
TypeError: unbound method **str**() must be called with student instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: why you have 2 __repr__ ?

Comment: what do you mean by put the full class ?

Comment: btw __repr__ is it's not used when you re using print , you need implement __str__

Comment: @BenyGj if `__str__` is not implemented then `__repr__` is used instead.

Comment: So i can print it with __repr__ and initialize with __init__ ?

Answer (score 2):

Putting attributes at the class level doesn't do anything on its own normally unless it's a `dataclass`. If that's not what you meant to do, then you need to write an `__init__` method, that's the constructor.

`dataclass` will also take care of `__repr__` for you.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date

@dataclass
class student:
    name: str = ""
    surname: str = ""
    number: int = 0
    birthday: date = 0
    grade: int = 0
    subjet: str = ""

# Note the normal plain ASCII quotes ' and "
# ‚test‘ is not going to work,
# either in running code or when highlighting code in a question
o = student('Alex', 'Hall', 123, date(1, 2, 3))

print(o)
```

The next problem is that all your fields are optional because you've specified default values, so making broken objects is easy. And since all the fields are in a single class, you will have to create a new object with the same name, birthday etc. every time you want to add a subject/grade. Maybe store a list of grade/subject pairs for each student instead.

Comment: the following is the output of the terminal : ImportError: No module named dataclasses

Comment: @anfaenger_tester then either upgrade your Python version, or if you didn't mean to use a dataclass go back to reading tutorials about classes because you're not following what they tell you to do.

Comment: @AlexHall the annotation is required on dataclass  fix your code, see here https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses/issues/2

Comment: i fixed it now.